# Excel IF Function Changing Calculation

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have been working on a simple sheet to track some values on a cash till for daily closeouts and am struggling with an issue regarding an IF function. In essence, what I want to do is have a "discrepancy" column (N) that calculates from the daily totals (J), but only when a value is entered into the "actual" column (L).

When entering data as a straight calculation, I receive a correct value:

```
Formula: =J18-L18 
Value: 0
```

When I introduce an IF calculation into the mix, I receive an "off" calculation and value:

```
Formula: =IF(NOT(ISBLANK(L18)),J18-L18, "")
Value: -1.13687E-13
```

This is the same for any variation of "not blank" that I tried:

```
Formula: =IF(L18<>"",J18-L18, "")
Value: -1.13687E-13
```

Why is the value result different for the same calculation when nested inside an IF function? Screenshot attached shows the same as outlined above but within the spreadsheet. I know the issue seems like it might be irrelevant being such a small number rounded off (and displaying 0) but I want to understand why this doesn't function the way I would figure it should.

[image: Example in sheet]

Comment: Worth noting that I tried this with concrete values (ie: 244.19), rather than other calculations within the sheet as I thought it may be rounding carried from elsewhere in the sheet. All cell values within the sheet were two digits, no rounding.

Comment: Root cause of the issue is the floating point arithmetic used in Excel (https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/78113/floating-point-arithmetic-may-give-inaccurate-results-in-excel). As to why it appears only when you nest your calculation into a function, I don't think we can give you a definite answer, maybe it triggers some changes in the background. I've tried to replicate your issue in Excel 2013, but it just always works correctly.

Comment: When extending out values to "Scientific" I don't have anything longer than two decimal places on any value except those that result from that IF function, so I don't follow how the floating point arithmetic would apply here.

Comment: @Xyr0: Computers work in binary.  0.50 is ½ (1/2), 0.25 is ¼ (1/4) and 0.75 is ¾ (3/4).  Any other ‘‘two decimal places’’ value *cannot* be expressed exactly in binary.

Comment: This is a really small value, and you're working with monetary values, so one option is to just round to about 4 decimal places, which is probably enough precision for your needs, and will hide the floating point error behind a 0.0000.

Answer (score 0):

You should round the till total and till actual to 2 places with

=round(whatever, 2)

that should give you a real zero in the till column and fix your "" problem